# Jquery session - one time execution of a script?

Tags: jquery

I have this slider that opens / closes when you click on it, but I also made it so that it opens on page load as well, but now the problem is **it opens on every page** (since it's on every page).

Is it possible to somehow make it start automatically only **once** per session?

Comment: https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: Use a session-lifetime cookie to keep track of whether you've already done the slider or not in this browser session.

Comment: Yea...that's what I was asking HOW to do.

Answer (score 0):

If for example, you mean a php session:

```
$html = $someHtml;
if (!isset($_SESSION['firstTime'])) {
    $html .= "<script>myJavaScriptFunction();</script>";
    $_SESSION['firstTime'] = "Nope";
}
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name){
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name){
        return unescape(y);
      }
    }
}

if(!getCookie("sliderOpen")){
 //Open your slider
 setCookie("sliderOpen", 1, 1/*time until cookie expires*/ );
}
```

---

`setCookie()` and `getCookie()` functions source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp